# Connect to iSeries database from docker windows container

Tags: .net, docker, db2

How can I connect to iSeries database from a windows container? It requires client access to be installed on machine, obviously it's not installed on the base image I'm using (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.6.2-20221108-windowsservercore-ltsc2016).
Is there a way to achieve that without installation? Maybe copying some dll's would help?

I tried to copy dll's as mentioned in this answer [Embedd cwbdc.dll from IBM i Client Access manually to console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230252/embedd-cwbdc-dll-from-ibm-i-client-access-manually-to-console-application) but I could not find 320 dlls. And when copying for example 'cwbdc.dll' into project's bin folder I get BadImageFormatException

Comment: Which apps are you using inside that container that connect to i-series?  Are those apps only using ODBC interface?  The key detail is that you might not need IBM i-access at all IF and ONLY IF your console-only apps can function with the tiny zero-install clidriver instead (requires suitable license file present in the container).

Comment: @mao It's a huge asp.net web app targeting 461.

Comment: I tried to install IMB i Access Client Solutions on a docker container based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` image by copying setup.exe downloaded from IBM website to the container and running command from this link https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/silent-install-access-client-solutions-win-ap-package but the installation not seems to be successful. After running this command I'm trying to verify installation by running 'wmic product where "Name like '%%IBM%%'" get Name' but nothing appears. @mao

Comment: It is unwise to try to force a product to do something for which it is not designed. Use your IBM support contract to ask IBM for recommendations, unless you are able to get the app working with the clidriver as previously mentioned.